# Appwrite JWT authentication

Tags: authentication, jwt, appwrite

I'm trying to execute Appwrite function by authenticated user (JWT). What I do:

1. I create email session

```
curl --location 'http://localhost/v1/account/sessions/email' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'X-Appwrite-Project: my_project_id' \
--data-raw '{
  "email": "email",
  "password": "password"
}'
```

2. As a result of the request in point 1 I get `Set-Cookie` header. I use it to get the JWT token:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost/v1/account/jwt' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --header 'X-Appwrite-Response-Format: 1.4.0' \ --header 'X-Appwrite-Project: my_project_id' \ --header 'Cookie: here I place the Set-Cookie value'
```

And I get proper token (with correct user id and session id.

3. Then I try to execute my function:

```
curl --location 'http://myFunctionUrl/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'X-Appwrite-Project: my_project_id' \
--header 'X-Appwrite-JWT: my_jwt_token' \
--header 'X-Appwrite-Response-Format: 1.4.0' \
--data 'some_parameters'
```

As I result I get error 400 with the message:

```
Execution error: Missing "execute" permission for role "users". Only ["any","guests"] scopes are allowed and ["users"] was given.
```

In Appwrite function settings I set "Execute Access" to "Users":
[Appwrite function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl5aw.png)
so I assume I should be able to execute the function as user.

If I change the "Execute Access" to "Any" or "Guests" then it is working, function returns proper result, so the request and parameters are fine. What am I doing wrong that I cannot execute this function as user?

Answer (score 0):

After adding the correct permission (for Users) to your function, you may need to redeploy the function once from the Appwrite Console.

[image: Screenshot of the Appwrite Function deployments on the Appwrite Console]

Please try the same and let me know if the issue still occurs.